# Paste variable value into URL query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a variable from session storage like this:

```
var my_variable = sessionStorage.getItem("some_value");
```

Using Jquery or plain JS how can I paste the value of `my_variable` into the current document URL, inside a query string?

**Example:** If `my_variable` has the value "Hello_world", then the document URL should look like this:

www.example.com/some_page/index.html?q="Hello_world"

Comment: You mean you want to navigate to the new url?

Comment: I was hoping to do this without a page refresh or URL redirect.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without redirection it's possible with History API:

**JS**

```
history.replaceState(history.state, '{your-new-url}', '{your-title(optional)}');
```

Also check, if the browser support is enough corresponding to your requirements.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).